# The polite term for a mistake

Tags: synonyms, phrasal-verbs, politeness

I heard this sentence in a movie, and I wanted to know the polite way to express this:

> They've f***ed up my reservation.

Comment: Jerry Seinfeld has some thoughts on Reservations:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A7uvttu8ct0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively one says "They have ruined my reservation" or "They have messed up my reservation". Hope these will help.

Comment: I would agree that _messed up_ can be used in place of the words the O.P. is asking about. One could also say _screwed up_, which is a bit more vulgar than _messed up_ but nowhere near as vulgar as _f***ed up_. I'm not in complete agreement with "ruined," though. It might work as a substitute in some contexts, but not in others. For example, if I say, "The mechanic has messed up my car," that means he has some more work to do; however, if I say, "The mechanic has ruined my car," that implies something more severe and perhaps less likely to be repairable.

Answer (score 6):

They've bungled my reservation.

They've mishandled my reservation.

Comment: I think _bungled_ is an excellent suggestion.

Comment: How about "botch" or "spoil"? @J.R.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be really polite, you'd remove any emotional reference to their mistake and its impact on you. So something more like this:

**They made an error with my reservation**

or even this to remove blame:

**There was a mistake made with my reservation**

Comment: To remove all implications of fault entirely you could say "There was an issue with my reservation." It loses all information about the nature of the problem, though.

Answer (score 0):

> They've messed up my reservation.

Means exactly the same thing, but isn't rude in the slightest.